# Are there any circumstances where the court could order authorities to seize subpoenaed materials in a civil suit?

Tags: united-states, civil-procedure, subpoena

As the title. I am aware that there are a number of punitive measures courts can take when parties do not comply with discovery. Is there point where the court can order the collection of materials by law enforcement?